# Matching characters between two strings - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, string-matching

I have two pieces of code which splits a string into single characters and returns it row by row. Does anyone know of any in-built functions which can essentially take the split strings in order to determine whether they are similar to each other ?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Aux.Name, X.number+1, 1) AS Split 
FROM 
    (SELECT 'Wes Davids' as Name) AS Aux
    INNER JOIN master..spt_values X ON X.number < LEN(Aux.Name)
WHERE X.type = 'P'
```

```
 1 W
 2 e
 3 s
 4 
 5 D
 6 a
 7 v
 8 i
 9 d
10 s
```

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Aux.Name, X.number+1, 1) AS Split 
FROM 
    (SELECT 'W Davids' as Name) AS Aux
    INNER JOIN master..spt_values X ON X.number < LEN(Aux.Name)
WHERE X.type = 'P'
```

```
 1 W
 2 
 3 D
 4 a
 5 v
 6 i
 7 d
 8 s
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @RichardHansell I've used `SOUNDEX` before but I wondered if there was a more accurate way to determine whether the two strings are practically the same by looking at each individual character e.g James Cook and J Cook

Comment: Yes, names are a particular subset of "fuzzy matching", they tend to work best with things like word replacement or distance algorithms.  Jaro-Winkler distance is a good place to start, but there's nothing built into SQL Server for this.  If you search around you should be able to find a TSQL implementation easily enough though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For splitting a string into [N-Grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram), specifically unigrams in your case, you should use [ngrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams). For example:

```
SELECT ng.* FROM dbo.ngrams8k('Wes Davids',1) AS ng;
```

**Returns:**

```
position    token
----------- ---------
1           W
2           e
3           s
4            
5           D
6           a
7           v
8           i
9           d
10          s
```

You can use it, for example, to quickly get the longest common substring between two strings as shown below. You can create a similarity score by dividing the length of the longest common substring (LCSS) by the length of the longest of the two strings (L2):

```
DECLARE
  @string1 VARCHAR(100) = 'Joe Cook',
  @string2 VARCHAR(100) = 'J Cook';

SELECT TOP (1) *, LCSS = LEN(TRIM(ng.token)), similarity = 1.*LEN(TRIM(ng.token))/b.L2
FROM (VALUES(
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN @string1      ELSE @string2 END,
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN @string2      ELSE @string1 END,
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN LEN(@string1) ELSE LEN(@string2)END,
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN LEN(@string2) ELSE LEN(@string1)END
)) AS b(S1,S2,L1,L2)
CROSS JOIN  master..spt_values            AS x
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8k(b.S1,x.number+1) AS ng
WHERE       x.[type] = 'P' 
AND         x.number < b.L1
AND         CHARINDEX(ng.token,b.S2) > 0
ORDER BY    LEN(TRIM(ng.token)) DESC
GO
```

**Returns:**

```
S1             S2           position             token      LCSS  Similarity
-------------- ------------ -------------------- ---------- ----- ---------------------------------------
J Cook         Joe Cook     3                    Cook       4     0.50000000000
```

You can get a better similarity score by subtracting the [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (lev) distance from the length of the shorter of the two strings (L1-Lev), then dividing that value by L2: 
(L1-Lev)/L2. You can use [Phil Factor's Levenshtein Function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-edit-distance-and-the-levenshtein-algorithm/) for this.

```
DECLARE
  @string1 VARCHAR(100) = 'James Cook',
  @string2 VARCHAR(100) = 'Jamess Cook';

SELECT 
  Lev        = dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(@string1,@string2), 
  Similarity = (1.*b.L1-dbo.LEVENSHTEIN(@string1,@string2))/b.L2
FROM (VALUES(
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN @string1      ELSE @string2 END,
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN @string2      ELSE @string1 END,
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN LEN(@string1) ELSE LEN(@string2)END,
  CASE WHEN LEN(@string1)<= LEN(@string2) THEN LEN(@string2) ELSE LEN(@string1)END
)) AS b(S1,S2,L1,L2)
GO
```

**Returns:**

```
Lev         Similarity
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           0.81818181818
```

This is an example of how to use the Levenshtein Distance for measuring similarity. There are other algorithms such as the [Damerau–Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) distance and [The Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).  Damerau–Levenshtein is more precise but slower (Phil Factor has a Damerau–Levenshtein function in the aforementioned link as well as a [Longest Common Subsequence function] in a different post[7](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-subsequence/). The formula for similarity is the same `(L1-DLev)/L2`. The Longest Common Subsequence (LCSSq) is more accurate (but slower) than the longest common substring, but uses the same formula for calculating a similarity score: `(LCSSq/L2)`

Hopefully this will get you started.